# Quadratic discriminant analysis (QDA) with qualitative predictors in R

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I need your help with a Statistical Learning homework in R.
I have to perform classification over this dataset: [mammographic masses](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mammographic-masses/) predicting Severity (0="not severe",1 = "severe) using these predictors:

- Age (quantitative)
- Margin (qualitative)
- Shape (qualitative)

Everything is fine and understandable when I use logistic regression, but I don't know if it's possible to run QDA (or linear discriminant analysis either), since two of the variables are qualitative.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be **no** you cannot use the usual form of LDA or QDA if your data points are binary. The reason for this is the following:

- LDA and QDA require you to estimate several parameters of a multivariate gaussian distribution: the mean(s), the covariance matrix
- How would you fit a multivariate gaussian on data that can only be equal to 0 or 1 ?

In his lecture notes, Andrew Ng specifically states that the assumption behind LDA is that the X data is continuous

See [here](https://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes2.pdf):